# Error in SECKFMDefaultPromptHandler: func=18: Unknown security function code

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-domino, lotus

I tried to set up a new Windows 7 KVM for my Lotus Domino and Java Eclipse environment.
I installed Lotus Notes 9.0.1 FP2 (incl. Domino Designer) and Eclipse Luna IDE.
Furthermore I added my c:\notes directory to windows paths.

When I started my java code which was working with the old KVM at the line

```
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, config.getNsfpwd());
```

the program gives me the Error

```
[0524:0002-0F44] 02.12.2014 09:10:35   Error in SECKFMDefaultPromptHandler: func=18: Unknown security function code.
```

Do you have any ideas how to get the code running?

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one installation of Notes on the path?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The Notes client was installed freshly.

Comment: Have you tried the createTrustedSession() method? That should cause you to be prompted for the password. It will be interesting to see if that works. Also since this is a fresh install, can we presume that you have fired up the Notes client, gone through the setup process, and that you can successfully connect with it to a Domino server?

Comment: When I tried the createTrustedSession() method I got the error message:

Comment: 2014-12-03 09:57:24,834 ERROR [main]: Exception
NotesException: Method is not available
 at lotus.domino.local.Session.NCreateTrustedSession(Native Method)
 at lotus.domino.local.Session.createTrustedSession(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createTrustedSession(Unknown Source)

I had the Notes client and designer already in use. 
After I opened the server I want to use first time in the Client the code after the createSession is running. But the error message when creating the session remains.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is way old, but now that I was requested to work a bit with Domino and Java, I'll add my findings here. That problem appeared to me because the password in the notes client used by the Java code was about to expire. Changing the password fixed it.

Regards.